# Dynamic Django-REST API Endpoint in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a view which calls results_chart.html which contains a jquery block which specifies an REST-API endpoint. This endpoint is currently hardcoded like:

```
var endpoint = '/api/solgeo/projects/2.json';
```

However of course I want the correct project id, which I can access in the {% block content %} section using Django templating. I.e. the project Id is specified by {{project.id}}. How can I access this project.id in my jQuery section? The html template in question is given by:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<script>
{% block jquery %}

var endpoint = '/api/solgeo/projects/2.json';  
var defaultData = []
var labels = []

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        var length = data.hourlys.length
        for (i=0; i<length; i++){
            defaultData[i] = data.hourlys[i].clock_time
            labels[i] = i.toString()
        }
        setChart()
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

function setChart(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# ??????',
                data: defaultData,
            }]
        }
    })
}


{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}

<h3>Project id: {{ project.id }}</h3>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12'>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    {% autoescape off %}
        project_id={{ project.id }} //Keep this js variable global
    {% endautoescape %}
</script>
```

Now you can access `project_id` variable into jquery.

OR

add hidden input into html / template

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ project.id }}" name="project_id" id="project_id" />
```

And fetch value into js

```
$("#project_id").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay sorry to bother everyone, think the solution is quitte simple. Replace the start of the example code with:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<script>
{% block jquery %}

var projectId = '{{project.id}}'
var endpoint = '/api/solgeo/projects/'+projectId.toString() + '.json'
```

...rest of the code...

Comment: Your solution will work but you have to keep all javascript in Template / Html file. which is not good practice. You need to keep javascript into js file and need to move to static/js folder so when on production server you fire a command of `collectstatic` it won't take this file into static folder.